# python making list of averages from dictionary of dictionaries: all averages same

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries, `d`:

```
d = {'redFish': {'redFish': 'inf', 'blueFish': 9, 'twoFish': 10, 'oneFish': 6},
'blueFish': {'redFish': 9, 'blueFish': 'inf', 'twoFish': 11, 'oneFish': 10},
'twoFish': {'redFish': 10, 'blueFish': 11, 'twoFish': 'inf', 'oneFish': 8},
'oneFish': {'redFish': 6, 'blueFish': 10, 'twoFish': 8, 'oneFish': 'inf'}}
```

I have a function that finds and returns the key-key-value pair with the lowest value:

```
lowestPair = ['name1', 'name2', float('inf')]
for name1 in d.keys():
    for name2 in d[name1].keys():
        if d[name1][name2] < lowestPair[2]:
            lowestPair = [name1, name2, d[name1][name2]]
```

My lowest pair acts as a cluster that will be treated as one entity. 
I am now trying to go through my dictionary of dictionaries, and for each species find the values which are the average between the species I am looking at, and both the species in my new cluster.

i.e. as redFish and oneFish are the species in lowest Pair, I want to find the average between redFish blueFish and oneFish Bluefish, and also the average between oneFish twoFish and oneFish blueFish.

I have a piece of code that does this:

```
averageList = []
for name in lowestPair[0:2]:
    for otherName in d[name].keys():
        if otherName not in lowestPair:
            average = (d[lowestPair[0]][otherName] + d[lowestPair[1]][otherName])/2
            nameDict[name][otherName] = average 
            averageList.append(average)
```

However, the average list returns as `[9, 9, 9, 9]` which is not the correct answer, as the average for redFish blueFish and oneFish Bluefish, and the average between oneFish twoFish and redFish twoFish should be `9` and `9.5`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it's because your dict is storing `int` instead of `float` for the numbers? Everytime you call `d[name1][name2]` or similar, I would try to wrap a `float()` around it to see if that helps.

Comment: @JasonKLai thanks for the suggestion, but this has not worked.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the averages are being calculated. My understanding is that the average between `redFish blueFish` and `oneFish Bluefish` is `(9 + 10)/2`, which would equal `9.5`, not `8`.

Comment: Is the code you have in the question exactly what you are using? Because when I copied and pasted your code into a Python script and changed the ints to floats, I got `[9.5, 9.0, 9.75, 8.5]`

Comment: @Brydenr apologies I used partially the wrong data when writing my question, and I have updated my question to be correct. You are right

Comment: @JasonKLai Yes the code is the same. Perhaps I was using `float` in the wrong place? where exactly did you use `float`

Comment: The reason why I ask if the code is the same, is because `nameDict` is not defined in the example code you provided, thus running it exactly as you wrote it would give an error. As a result, I thought maybe there was more code you weren't showing us. Anyway, I posted an answer with the exact modified code I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code with a couple of minor calculations, I was able to get `[9.5, 9.0, 9.75, 8.5]`

The two changes I made was that I had to cast the output of dictionary `d` to a `float()`, and I changed `nameDict` to `d`, since `nameDict` was not defined in the example code provided. Here is the resulting code below:

```
d = {'redFish': {'redFish': 'inf', 'blueFish': 9, 'twoFish': 10, 'oneFish': 6}, 'blueFish': {'redFish': 9, 'blueFish': 'inf', 'twoFish': 11, 'oneFish': 10}, 'twoFish': {'redFish': 10, 'blueFish': 11, 'twoFish': 'inf', 'oneFish': 8}, 'oneFish': {'redFish': 6, 'blueFish': 10, 'twoFish': 8, 'oneFish': 'inf'}}

lowestPair = ['name1', 'name2', float('inf')]
for name1 in d.keys():
    for name2 in d[name1].keys():
        if float( d[name1][name2] ) < lowestPair[2]:
            lowestPair = [name1, name2, d[name1][name2]]

averageList = []
for name in lowestPair[0:2]:
    for otherName in d[name].keys():
        if otherName not in lowestPair:
            average = (float( d[lowestPair[0]][otherName] ) + float( d[lowestPair[1]][otherName] ))/2
            d[name][otherName] = average 
            averageList.append(average) 

print( averageList )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear help, I now understand where the floats should go.